# Problems with animation

Tags: android, animation

I have some troubles with Interpolator...
    I tried to make fadeIN/OUT but this function does not work. I have set delay 1000ms, but fading effect is not shown. Could you help me out? I checked some tutorials and all should be set correctly except layout width/height which should not be presented in XML. When i remove them there is message that those fields are mandatory:(

```
XMLs:
FADEIN
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

---------------------

FADEOUT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0">

</alpha>

---------
Main Activity
public class WelcomePage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_page);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread(){  
            public void run(){
                Intent mainMenu = new Intent(WelcomePage.this,mainMenu.class);
                WelcomePage.this.startActivity(mainMenu); 
                WelcomePage.this.finish(); 
                overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fadein,R.layout.fadeout); 
            }

        },GCEngine.GAME_THREAD_DELAY);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this to `fade_out`:

```
android:fillAfter="true"
```

Than use this code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread(){  
        public void run(){
            Intent mainMenu = new Intent(WelcomePage.this,mainMenu.class);
            WelcomePage.this.startActivity(mainMenu); 
            overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fadein,R.layout.fadeout); 
            WelcomePage.this.finish(); 
        }

},GCEngine.GAME_THREAD_DELAY);
```

Comment: It is not working. Still same. First second is screen as if new activity is created (white page / blue toolbar) FadeOut is not fading:(